# Select.Pdf load existing .pdf

Tags: c#

The documentation for Select.Pdf for .Net v 2.22 uses the following code snippet to load an existing document. However, in the actual library there is no constructor with that takes a string as a parameter. Is anyone aware of how to load an existing .pdf? I am using the Community Edition of this product as well.

```
string file = Server.MapPath("~/files/doc1.pdf");

// load the pdf document
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(file);

// add a new page to the document
PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();

// create a new pdf font (component standard font)
PdfFont font = doc.AddFont(PdfStandardFont.Helvetica);
font.Size = 20;

// create text element and add it to the new page
PdfTextElement text = new PdfTextElement(100, 100,
    "Sample text added to an existing pdf document.", font);
page.Add(text);

// save pdf document
doc.Save(Response, false, "Sample.pdf");

// close pdf document
doc.Close();
```

Comment: What is "Select.Pdf"? [This one](http://selectpdf.com/)? If yes, [the documentation says](http://selectpdf.com/docs/T_SelectPdf_PdfDocument.htm), that there _is_ a constructor that takes a filen ame as a parameter.

Comment: I've also downloaded the latest version (16.2) from their website and the .net 4 DLLs also contain this `PdfDocument(string filename)` constructor.

Comment: @UweKeim Did you download the community version?

Comment: I did download the full version. The Community Edition has fewer constructors. I guess that this is based on a much older version. So you probably cannot apply full version examples to the Comunity Edition.

Comment: That's good enough of an answer for me. If you make it an actual answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Jason, here are my comments as an answer:

I've downloaded the latest version (16.2) from the [Select.Pdf website](http://selectpdf.com/) and the .net 4 DLLs do contain the `PdfDocument(string filename)` constructor, [just as described in their documentation](http://selectpdf.com/docs/T_SelectPdf_PdfDocument.htm).

I've also downloaded the Community Edition and checked the same `PdfDocument` class. In this edition, the constructor has fewer overloads.

So I guess that the Community Edition is a much older version and you cannot apply the full version examples to the Community Edition.